# Непонятный счетчик и работа со строками

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

У меня есть исходник программы которую я писал пару месяцев назад, знал тогда С++ хуже чем сейчас, поэтому использовал пару фрагментов из форумов Программистов. Программа компилируется и работает отлично.
Собственно непонятен момент с:

```
sentence[(counter++)%number]=word;
```

и

```
if(word.find_first_of(".!?") != string::npos)
```

вот код полностью:

Задание: Открыть для чтения файл. Вывести предложение с указанным с клавиатуры числом слов.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>  
#include <string>  

using namespace std;  

int main()  
{   
  cout<<"Enter 0 for exit\n";    
  while (true)         
  {  
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); //поддержка российской раскладки  
                                    //для систем от Microsoft  
    int number, counter=0;   
    string word;  

    ifstream fin("text.txt");  
    if (!fin.is_open())             //проверка на открытие файла  
      {                            //и выдача ошибки если это не удалось  
        cout << "File isn't found." << endl;  
        return 0;                  //сразу выход из программы  
      }   

    cout << "Enter number words: ";   
    cin >> number;  
    if (!number) return 0;         // если введен 0, то выход  
    string* sentence = new string[number]; //динамический массив строк  

    while (!fin.eof())   
      {  
        fin>>word;  
        sentence[(counter++)%number]=word;  //непонятность 1  

        if(word.find_first_of(".!?") != string::npos)  //непонятность 2  
          {  
            if (counter==number)   
              {  
                for (int i=0; i<number; i++)  
                cout << sentence[i] << " ";  
                cout << endl;  
              }  
            counter=0;  
            word = "";  
          }  
      }  
    delete [] sentence;  
    }  
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (!fin.eof())   // пока не дошли до конца файла, но мне больше нравится fin.good()
  {  
    fin>>word;  // считываем слово
    sentence[(counter++)%number]=word;  // копируем считанное слово в массив слов по индексу (counter++)%number.
    // т.е. если вылезли за number слов - начинаем с 0 и переписываем уже имеющиеся слова
    if(word.find_first_of(".!?") != string::npos)  // ищем символы окончания предложения
    //  если их нет - получается индекс string::npos, иначе какое-то число - номер символа в строке.
      {  
        if (counter==number)   // выводим найденное предложение
          {  
            for (int i=0; i<number; i++)  
            cout << sentence[i] << " ";  
            cout << endl;  
          }  
        counter=0;  
        word = "";  
      }  
  }
```